# Async Task.Delay CancellationToken

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, cancellationtokensource

I was looking for a way to delay some expensive search in TextChanged event. 
The following code waits 300ms after the user has finished typing and then searches.

```
    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300), this.throttleCts.Token) // if no keystroke occurs, carry on after 500ms
            .ContinueWith(
                delegate { PerformSearch(e.NewText); }, 
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Is there any more elegant equivalent async/await code for the above sample?

I replaced with this but it's throwing TaskCanceledException

```
    await Task.Delay(300, this.throttleCts.Token);
    PerformSearch(e.NewText);
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard way with async-await is to catch the `OperationCanceledException`.

```
private async void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(300, this.throttleCts.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        return;
    }
    PerformSearch(e.NewText);
}
```